# Type of a list is not recognized Python

Tags: python, list, types

I'm trying to write a program that can recognize a list but the program doesn't work

```
co = {"value1": "string", "value2": [{"value": "list"}]}
print(type(co["value2"]))
if type(co["value2"]) == list:
  print("list!")
  # This is the desired result
else:
  print("other!")
```

The console only shows the following:

```
<class 'list'>
other!
```

The console should show the following:

```
<class 'list'>
list!
```

I've already tried to fix the error by just setting a list as "co" but the result is the same!
Maybe I'm doing very badly and have overlooked a very small thing, but I haven't found anything
The list should recognize it so that it is processed differently than a set type
Maybe someone can help me there or has ideas to help solve the problem.

Comment: I ran your example and got your desired result. Out of curiousity what version of Python are you running?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Python 3.9

Comment: The only way this could have failed is if you had accidentally reassigned the name `list` somewhere previously in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works fine, I think you might use `list` as a variable name above somewhere in your code and you have overridden its main functionality.

although,
it is better to use [isinstance()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_isinstance.asp) for type checking.

so you can change your `if` condition like this:

```
if isinstance(co["value2"], list):
```

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem and I updated the Python version